# want to convert and save customer chat URLs to wmv files

Tags: python-3.x

I have our Customer chat in form of Twillio URLs in Excel file. I need to transcribe these into text. I am using python with Watson API to transcribe these chats. I have converted one single chat, but to automate, I need to put either batch processing or need to save all URLs as `.wmv` file and then pick these chats one by one with batch processing .

Please help me as I am new in python. attach are same urls.

https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACd68f755feffad27946149db85d3d6a04/Recordings/REba7beeb64e48ad0a9baf32d809b14b31

https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACd68f755feffad27946149db85d3d6a04/Recordings/REb5ae5641a98dbd326e76ddd0cd7b2a15

https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACd68f755feffad27946149db85d3d6a04/Recordings/REde28cc1b1d89047b77ef5232b0e76e9f

https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACd68f755feffad27946149db85d3d6a04/Recordings/REd36ae0867c7f87a2fd2ae4bafeeace6b

https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACd68f755feffad27946149db85d3d6a04/Recordings/REa1310a17d45717bf81488945a3ade9fc

Regards
Rakesh

Comment: You have the code to extract chat from a single URL and you need to go through a list of URLs to process all of them? If so, provide the code (as simplified as possible) that you are currently using. Also, are these talks with real customers (cannot listen to them at the moment)? Are you allowed to publish this kind of info publicly?

Comment: Yes, project is related to real customer.

Comment: No, will not allow to publish the info publicly.

Comment: 4. Upgrade Watson-developer-cloud
i. pip install --upgrade watson-developer-cloud

5. Install python sdk
6. pip install C:\Users\rakesh.chandra\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python-sdk-develop
7. Install curl to root directory
a. C:\Users\rakesh.chandra\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32

Comment: 8. Access the flac file from destination
curl -X POST -u a3af9723-8e5d-4632-a7b1-338bb1449f29:wq3qtuOi5lsC --header "Content-Type: audio/flac" --data-binary @D:/Statistics_Team/Rakesh/speech/audio-file.flac "https://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api/v1/recognize

Comment: 9. Access the narrowband .wav file
curl -X POST -u a3af9723-8e5d-4632-a7b1-338bb1449f29:wq3qtuOi5lsC --header "Content-Type: audio/wav" --data-binary @D:/Statistics_Team/Rakesh/speech/b2c_rakesh.wav "https://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api/v1/recognize?model=en-US_NarrowbandModel"

Comment: It is converting my wmv file to text. now I am tying to automate the process. I have URLs in Excel. I tried a little with following code. excel_document = openpyxl.load_workbook('D:\Statistics_Team\Rakesh\speech\data\twillio.xlsx')
sheet = excel_document.get_sheet_by_name('urls')

sheet = excel_document.get_sheet_by_name('urls')

print(twillio[urls['H2']].value)


xl = pd.ExcelFile("D:\\Statistics_Team\\Rakesh\\speech\\data\\twillio.xlsx")
df = xl.parse("urls")
df.iloc[[2],[8]]

Comment: now I am trying this also: - xl.sheet_names

df = xl.parse("urls")

 df.loc[["Call_URL"]]

df["Call_URL"].loc[2,8]

df.iloc[:2,8]

AudioSegment.from_wav(""D:\\Statistics_Team\\Rakesh\\speech\\data\\twillio.xlsx, df.iloc[[2],[8]]  Downloads/REb5ae5641a98dbd326e76ddd0cd7b2a15.wav").export("C:/Users/pallavi.pundir/Downloads/file.wav", format="wav")


AudioSegment.from_wav(""df.iloc[[2],[7]]").export("C:/Users/pallavi.pundir/Downloads/file.wav", format="wav")